# Two one to many association on a LinkTable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4.1, fluent-interface

I have a LinkTable named: BlogsBlogPosts that relates two other tables named: Blogs and BlogPosts together, I want the link table to appear in the list of entities and There will be two one to many relationships defined on the linktable am I correct to define it like this?:

```
public class BlogsBlogPostConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<BlogsBlogPost>
{
    public BlogsBlogPostConfiguration()
    {
        this.HasRequired(bb => bb.Blog)
        .WithMany(b => b.BlogsBlogPosts)
        .HasForeignKey(bb =>bb.BlogID);

        this.HasRequired(bb => bb.BlogPost)
       .WithMany(bp => bp.BlogsBlogPosts)
       .HasForeignKey(bb => bb.BlogPostID);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The only question which remains for me is: What about the primary key property of `BlogsBlogPost`? Two options:

- You either have a distinct key property like `public int BlogsBlogPostID { get; set; }` or `public int ID { get; set; }` in this entity. In this case combinations of (`BlogID`, `BlogPostID`) don't have to be unique.
- Or you have a composite key consisting of (`BlogID`, `BlogPostID`). You would have to mark this with the `[Key]` annotation or define it in Fluent API:

  ```
  this.HasKey(bbp => new { bbp.BlogID, bbp.BlogPostID });
  ```

  Now combinations of (`BlogID`, `BlogPostID`) must be unique. This is more of a "*many-to-many relationship with additional data in the link table*" type of relationship.

Both models are possible. Which to use depends on your business needs.

Comment: Thank you very much, BlogsBlogPost has a composite key I define in the entity like this:  [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
        public Guid BlogID { get; set; }

        [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
        public Guid BlogPostID { get; set; }

Comment: @mz1378: OK, that's fine, it's the same then as the Fluent mapping in my answer.